# How is the Signal-to-noise ratio distance defined?

Tags: probability-theory

For two probability measures, or two random variables, I wonder how their Signal-to-noise ratio distance is defined? I encounter this concept in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_metric#Examples).

For a probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$, its signal-to-noise ratio is defined as the ratio between its expectation and its deviation. But how is the distance defined in terms of the ratio?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I think it is just the signal-to-noise-ration of the difference...

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks! If that is the case, the distance between a probability measure and itself is undefined, since the difference between it and itself is zero measure, and has zero expectation and deviation. That is not well defined.

Comment: Yes, its undefined in that case but usually one would say that it is infinity. There is only signal but no noise, hence, its ratio is biggest possible, i.e. infinity.